# Undeploying VMware Lab Manager VMs after trial license expires

Tags: vmware-esxi, licensing, uninstall, vmware-vcenter

I played around with Lab Manager for a while, deploying a couple of machines.
Meanwhile, the trial license has expired, and now I can't seem to "get rid" of the VMs (seems they are uncontrollable by the vCenter).
Every page on the Lab Manager web interface gives me the expired license notification - no controlling option.
Attempting to uninstall the Lab Manager product gives me a warning about existing deployed machines (...), recommending I undeploy them first.
(Note: All information inside them is completely dispensable - no ideological problem with brute force shut down and/or removal)
Running ESXi 4.0U1 cluster, all VMs are on NetApp storage.

Thanks in advance,
-- Shahar

Answer (score 2):

Try connecting to the esx host directly, more options are enabled.